# More efficient way to query for a row that does not exist SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have this query that joins back to a table to calculate a score based on certain criteria. In some cases rows do not exist in the target table where something needs to return, so I have the current query below, it's killing performance and sometimes does not return as this particular query is a sub query within the larger scoring set of queries in SSRS and SQL Server.

```
   SELECT
                G.[Name], 
                G.[ID], 
                A.IName, 
                A.ItID, 
                COUNT(A.IHid) OVER() AS ICount, 
                G.[AllComplete], 
                G.[IComplete], 
                G.[IStatus], 
                A.[Group], 
                A.[Status] AS [Status], 
                A.[Type] AS [Type]
   FROM TableA A
         INNER JOIN TableG G
                ON A.ID = G.ID AND G.id IS Not NULL
   WHERE G.[ID] = ('048') 
   AND NOT ( A.ItID = '' ) 
   AND NOT ( A.[Status] IN ('NA'))
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 0, NULL, NULL, 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A'
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                              FROM TableA A 
                                    INNER JOIN TableG G 
                                           ON A.ID = G.ID AND G.id IS Not NULL
                               WHERE  G.[ID] = ('048') 
                               AND NOT ( A.ItID = '' ) 
                               AND NOT ( A.[Status] IN ('NA')))
```

Comment: This whole thing is a subquery? How do you know this is the portion that is hurting performance? Could you make this a cte prior to the main query? Kind of hard to offer much help here with no context.

Comment: Normally, "some rows don't exist" would imply `LEFT JOIN`, but it's not clear here what data always exists (if any).  Especially if this is part of a subquery, usually you'd just return the empty set (no rows), instead of a dummy row.

Comment: Your first UNION has a WHERE clause which is the same as your 2nd UNION with a NOT EXIST? Care to give us a context of what you are trying to achieve here? Do you just want a row of 'N/A' for the ID's not that are not in your first UNION? If that's a case, there's no need for your 2nd UNION.

Comment: This portion of the entire query takes the results and uses them for scoring.

Comment: How is N/A use for scoring?

Comment: This portion of the entire query takes the results and uses them for scoring in another portion of the query. To return a result this is the best way (for now) I could figure how to return a result. The prior query here did not included anything from the UNION on, once that was added that's how I found out it was truly hurting performance. Rows will not always exist in TableA or TableG if A.ItID = ''

Comment: It honestly makes no difference whether or not it returns NA or ''. Returning the 0 is the most important part if no rows exist

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a UNION at all.Your goal is vague but if I understand this correctly, what you want is to return all the values from your first table where there's an ID = 048 and when it doesnt match that, you want N/A.

If this is true, then you dont need a UNION. Just do a LEFT JOIN from A to G(or G to A -- depending on what you want). This will return all your data from table A with N/A then return one with data -- which is the 048

FYI: Your table shouldn't contain ' ', if this is the case, you should update this to NULL, then do a NOT IN NULL, rather than a WHERE NOT (' ')

```
SELECT
            G.[Name], 
            G.[ID], 
            A.IName, 
            A.ItID, 
            COUNT(A.IHid) OVER() AS ICount, 
            G.[AllComplete], 
            G.[IComplete], 
            G.[IStatus], 
            A.[Group], 
            A.[Status] AS [Status], 
            A.[Type] AS [Type]
   FROM TableA A
      LEFT JOIN TableG G ON A.ID = G.ID AND G.[ID] = ('048') 
   WHERE  A.ItID NOT IN ('') -- this really should be NULL
   AND    A.[Status] NOT IN ('N/A')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your "problem" is with the 2nd query from `UNION ALL`.

I've re-wrote your query using `LEFT JOIN` and `ISNULL` / `IIF` on columns so they produce the same output(you can use `CASE` if `IIF` is not supported):

```
SELECT  ISNULL(G.[Name], 'N/A')                     AS Name, 
        ISNULL(G.[ID], 'N/A')                           AS ID, 
        IIF(G.ID IS NULL, 'N/A', A.IName)               AS IName, 
        IIF(G.ID IS NULL, 'N/A', A.ItID)                AS ItID, 
        IIF(G.ID IS NULL, 0, COUNT(A.IHid) OVER())  AS ICount, 
        G.[AllComplete], 
        G.[IComplete], 
        ISNULL(G.[IStatus], 'N/A')                  AS IStatus, 
        IIF(G.ID IS NULL, 'N/A', A.[Group])         AS [Group], 
        IIF(G.ID IS NULL, 'N/A', A.[Status])            AS [Status], 
        IIF(G.ID IS NULL, 'N/A', A.[Type])          AS [Type]
FROM    TableA A
    LEFT JOIN TableG G
        ON A.ID = G.ID 
WHERE       A.[ID] = ('048') -- replaced here G.ID with A.ID, since these need to be equal
    AND NOT  A.ItID = ''
    AND NOT  A.[Status] IN ('NA')
```

One thing, you may want to extract an identifier that's being fed from outer query, that you can maybe use in your processing. Can't really say which value comes from outer query with this sample.

Hope this helps.